# HTTP status code 406 appropriate for "Content not available in your country"? If not, what's appropriate?

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, multilingual, http-status-codes, http-status-code-406

I have a multilingual website. The content language is defined via the URL:

> www.example.com/en_gb/content/right/here/

To make sure search engines understand that the content is also available in other languages, I make use of the alternate links in my page's `<head/>`:

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/en_au/content/right/here/" hreflang="en-AU" rel="alternate">
<link href="http://www.example.com/fr_be/content/right/here/" hreflang="fr-BE" rel="alternate">
<link href="http://www.example.com/nl_be/content/right/here/" hreflang="nl-BE" rel="alternate">
<link href="http://www.example.com/en_ca/content/right/here/" hreflang="en-CA" rel="alternate">
<link href="http://www.example.com/fr_ca/content/right/here/" hreflang="fr-CA" rel="alternate">
```

Now my question: What shall I do in case someone requests the page with a valid locale (a local that is usually supported by my website),  but the current page is not available for that locale?

Currently I write to the page "This content is not available for your country" and respond with [HTTP status code 404 Not Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) to make sure search engines don't index this page.

Could I also make use of the [HTTP status code 406 Not Acceptable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) to make sure search engines understand even better that this page is also available in other languages? Would that status code even be appropriate? If so, how would I respond with the alternate links while at the same time showing a page to my users? This is what the RFC says:

> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using distinct URLs for each language, so a 404 would be the appropriate status code to use in this instance.

If the different language resources were all available at the same URL and you used the `Accept-language` request header to determine which one to send, and the client didn't accept any of the languages you had available, then 406 would be the right choice.